# Assign object properties returned from a function to variables with different names

Tags: javascript

Might sound complicated, but let me show you with code

```
const createCharacter = () => {
    ...
    ...
    return [name, age];
};

const [userName, userAge] = createRefreshToken();
```

But I need to create the same **userName** and **userAge** variables when the function returns an object not an array

```
return { name, age };
```

or with the same variables' names

```
return { userName, userAge};
```

Comment: you can destructure based on the property names of the object that you return `const {name, age} = ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return an object from a function and destructure([Read](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)) it with a new reference variable as

```
const { name: userName, age: userAge } = createCharacter();
```

```js
const createCharacter = () => {
  const name = "test Name",
    age = 20;
  // ...
  // ...
  return { name, age };
};

const { name: userName, age: userAge } = createCharacter();
console.log(userName);
console.log(userAge);
```

or You can create a new property when you return object from a function.

```js
const createCharacter = () => {
  const name = "test Name",
    age = 20;
  // ...
  // ...
  return { userName: name, userAge: age };
};

const { userName, userAge } = createCharacter();
console.log(userName);
console.log(userAge);
```